# i just added a new area to my code, however, it wont let me click on any of them now

Tags: tabs

I was busy working on one of my websites, when I had a thought to add a coding tab to it. So, I got a picture, I wrote the code, and now, when I try to access it, it shows every tab as empty. I don't know if this is a syntax or not, So any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: it doesn't work. Help?]

Comment: Please post your failing code rather than linking a screen-shot. SO strives to not be dependent on remote sites too much.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your HTML is not valid. Already in line 1: Close the `div` tag: `>`-symbol is missing. Later the `<A`-tag is invalid, too.

Finally your unordered lists have no items. Try code like this:

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It has work partially as I can see the tabs, but it won't allow me to see inside. I'm very confused as i edited the code just as commented, but still nothing.